# HTML tags inside xml, how to parse correctly in Android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I need to parse this xml.  I am trying dom parser.

I am not able to put html tags in CDATA becuase the result is fetched from a webservice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<sendgps>
<pin>1231771972</pin>
<deviceid>9774d56d682e549c</deviceid>
<balance>0.50 </balance>
<msg><b>This is a</b> test. <a href="http://www.google.com">Click</a> to go to website<br></msg>
<errorcode>0</errorcode>
</sendgps>
```

Comment: That is not XML.  You need to contact the webservice and ask them to send valid XML, or replace them with a decent service.

Comment: this is what I am getting from webservice.   How can I parse this?

Comment: You should complain to the webservice.  If you have no choice, use JSoup.

Comment: @SLaks, please post your comment as answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should complain to the webservice.

If they continue lying about their output format, use JSoup.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem. What I am doing is

1. Parse XML fields with SAX parser (you can use DOM also)
2. Strore fields contained in HTML in the separate fields inside my objects each one representing an entity inside my XML.
3. Parse HTML fields with JSoup. http://jsoup.org/ It's very handy and doing its job well. You can get more familiar with it through their cookbook: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/